# Bullet List Indentation not showing up in the wordpress

Tags: css, editor, visual-editor

In wordpress, I have written on article and in that I have bullet list to showcase but my indentation is greyed out, and not able to indent the list further as you can see in the sreenshots.

I want to move bullet list **Need** and **Cost** **Further** but not able to do that and hence they are looking as if they are not part of my heading.

[image]

**Below is the consequence of no indentation.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to address this, if you only have access to the block editor, would be to click on the three dots, edit the block as HTML and add something like this:

```
<li style="margin-left: 60px">
```

(Change the value to suit.) It may not show in the block editor, but will when you load the page.

To handle this site-wide using CSS, you could use the Simple Custom CSS and JS plugin for example, and add a rule like this:

```
li { margin-left: 60px; }
```

... but that would have to be customized to your site to work properly since you probably don't want to affect ALL list items.

Comment: This is time consuming since for every post we need to do this ...can we have global settings in the wordpress by which we can do this? any wordpress settings or plugin?

Comment: I see, that's true. Yes, you could handle it site-wide using CSS, potentially, but you'd need a way to leave normal list items unaffected.